# MSAccess: Return query for specific date from datetime value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to run a query from a linked table in MS SQL Server that has a datetime field. I'm trying to run a simple query to search for records for a specific date (`#03/24/2018#`), but since the datetime field has the time as well, I am not getting any records unless I specify the time range using BETWEEN with the time (`Between #03/24/2018 00:00:00 AM# And #03/24/2018 11:59:59 PM#`).

Original query which does not return desired output:

```
SELECT *
WHERE MyDateTimeField) = #3/24/2018#;
```

Query

```
SELECT *
WHERE MyDateTimeField) Between #3/24/2018 00:00:00 AM# And #3/24/2018 23:59:59#);
```

Is there a workaround to this as to not have to use a BETWEEN operator with the time?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid time portion, check for`MyDateTimeField`equal/greater than searched day and less than next day:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    MyDateTimeField >= #3/24/2018# 
  AND 
    MyDateTimeField < DateAdd("d",1,#3/24/2018#);
```

In opposite of converting`MyDateTimeField`to date, this does not prevent index usage and handles`Null`Values on`MyDateTimeField`.